# QMapControl проблема с яндекс картами

Tags: c++, yandex-maps-api, qt5, google-maps, tilemap

Захотелось отображать яндекс карты в QMapControl, для этого создал yandexMapAdapter

```
    YandexMapAdapter::YandexMapAdapter(   )
    : TileMapAdapter("vec01.maps.yandex.net", "/tiles?l=map&v=3.340.0&x=%2&y=%3&z=%1&lang=ru_RU", 256, 0, 21)
{}
```

Все прекрасно отображается, однако координаты по Y имеют какое-то смещение, один и тот же дом имеет разные координаты при использовании имеющегося googleMapAdapter и моего yandexMapAdapter. Скорее всего нужно переопределить эти функции:

```
    QPoint TileMapAdapter::coordinateToDisplay(const QPointF& coordinate) const
{
    qreal x = (coordinate.x()+180) * (mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)/360.; // coord to pixel!
    qreal y = (1-(log(tan(PI/4+deg_rad(coordinate.y())/2)) /PI)) /2  * (mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize);

    return QPoint(int(x), int(y));
}

QPointF TileMapAdapter::displayToCoordinate(const QPoint& point) const
{
    qreal longitude = (point.x()*(360/(mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)))-180;
    qreal latitude = rad_deg(atan(sinh((1-point.y()*(2/(mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)))*PI)));

    return QPointF(longitude, latitude);

}
```

Но какие формулы нужно использовать для яндекс карт? может кто-то уже это делал, если не трудно подскажите куда копать или дайте ссылку на формулы.

Comment: Y - координата в какой проекции? Или под Y координатой вы имеете в виду долготу ?

Comment: Широта имеет смещение, как удалось нагуглить это связано с тем, что Яндекс основан на эллипсоиде, а не на сфере как у гугла\OSM, но как исправить формулу пока ума не приложу

Comment: А в смысле исправить? Это просто разные системы координат.

Comment: Судя по всему, имеется в виду X/Y в метрах, а Y является широтой в проекции UTM.  А проекция делается для какой-то геодезической системы координат на эллипсоиде (или сфероиде) B/L (широта/долгота в градусах).
Если вы хотите получить координаты на яндекс картах такими же как на гугл картах, то вам придётся взять координаты с яндекс карт в их проекции (X/Y метры), перевести в геодезические координаты в системе яндекс карт, перевести в геодезические координаты в системы гугл карт, и выполнить их проецирование в проекцию гугл карт

Comment: Попробуйте найти EPSG коды геодезических систем гугл/яндекс карт, зная эти коды вы сможете перевеодить геодезические координаты из одной системы в другую (широта долгота в градусах). Формулами тут особо не отделаешься, разве что приближенно очень, либо писать прям реально всю математику полностью.

Comment: [Вот тут можно найти по коду описание системы координат](http://epsg.io/)

Comment: Вот вдогонку - использование `gdal` для конвертирования по EPSG кодам: [Вопрос на stackexchange Simple gdal coordinate conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167069/simple-gdal-coordinate-conversion)

Comment: 3857 - Это код проекции Меркатора на сфере
3395 - Это код проекции Меркатора на эллипсоиде WGS84

[Пруф](https://www.politerm.com/zuludoc/tile_projections.html)

Comment: А ещё:

`Работа с Яндекс.Картами с помощью API возможна в обеих проекциях (см. ymaps.projection.wgs84Mercator и ymaps.projection.sphericalMercator).`

Это из [теории](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/theory/index-docpage/) к яндекс картам

Comment: Так что возможно, вам просто url доступа к картам надо поменять или типа того

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот исправленные функции для WGS84

```
    QPointF YandexMapAdapter::displayToCoordinate( const QPoint& point ) const
{
    qreal longitude = (point.x()*(360/(mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)))-180; // pix per grad

    qreal ypos = asin( tanh( (1-point.y()*(2/(mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)))*PI ) );
    qreal n = 0.003356551468879694;
    qreal k = 0.00000657187271079536;
    qreal h = 1.764564338702e-8;
    qreal m = 5.328478445e-11;

    qreal g = ypos;
    qreal l = g + n * sin( 2 * g ) + k * sin( 4 * g ) + h * sin( 6 * g ) + m * sin( 8 * g );
    qreal latitude = rad_deg( l );

    return QPointF( longitude, latitude );

}

QPoint YandexMapAdapter::coordinateToDisplay( const QPointF& coordinate ) const
{
    qreal x = (coordinate.x()+180) * (mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize)/360.; // coord to pixel!

    qreal y = deg_rad( coordinate.y() );
    qreal e = 0.081819790992114408;
    qreal lat = atanh( sin( y ) ) - e * atanh( e * sin( y ) ); 
    qreal pixLat = (1 - lat /PI)/2  * (mNumberOfTiles*mTileSize);

    return QPoint( int( x ), int( pixLat ) );
}
```